# Creating RouteUrl from Path and Params

Tags: typescript

I am extracting `params` from `path` using this code:

````
/**
 * Splits input Path on `/` and returns a union of segments.
 * It uses {@link https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types tail recursive conditional type} approach to deal with performance issues for very long paths
 *
 * @example
 * ```
 * type Segments = PathSegments<'/courses/:courseId/classes/:classId'>;
 * //   ^? "" | "courses" | ":courseId" | "classes" | ":classId"
 * ```
 */
type PathSegments<
  Path extends string,
  Accumulator extends string = never
> = Path extends `${infer Left}/${infer Right}`
  ? PathSegments<Right, Accumulator | Left>
  : Accumulator | Path;

/**
 * Creates an object having
 * keys = filtered PathSegments that starts with `:` and
 * value = string
 *
 * Uses {@link https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as key remapping} to suppress any union members that don't begin with `:`
 *
 * @example 1 - when there are no dynamic params in Path
 * ```
 * type Params = RouteParams<'/courses/classes'>;
 * //   ^? {}
 * ```
 *
 * @example 2 - when there are dynamic params in Path
 * ```
 * type Params = RouteParams<'/courses/:courseId/classes/:classId'>;
 * //   ^? { courseId: string; classId: string }
 * ```
 */
type RouteParams<Path extends string> = {
  [PathSegment in PathSegments<Path> as PathSegment extends `:${infer RouteParam}`
    ? RouteParam
    : never]: string;
};
````

Now, I am trying to create a RouteUrl from Path and its extracted Params like so:

```
type RouteUrl<
  Path extends string,
  Params extends RouteParams<Path>
> = Path extends `${infer Left}/:${infer Param}/${infer Right}`
  ? `${Left}/${Params[Param]}/${RouteUrl<Right, Params extends RouteParams<Right> ? Params : never>}`
  : Path extends `${infer Left}/:${infer Param}`
  ? `${Left}/${Params[Param]}`
  : Path;
```

This is how you test the `RouteUrl` type:

```
type Url = RouteUrl<'/courses/:courseId/classes/:classId', { courseId: '123'; classId: '456' }>;
```

But for some reason, typescript is giving me error for `Params[Param]` used in `RouteUrl` type.

The exact error message is:

```
Type 'Params[Param]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.
  Type 'Params[string]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.
    Type 'RouteParams<Path>[string]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.ts(2322)
Type 'Param' cannot be used to index type 'Params'.ts(2536)
```

Here is the [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghsAFgZQgcwLYQHbAM4A8AUFLAolBAB7A4AmeUewATgJbZoA0JUAggGMBAVwzCANggD2LSjXqNm7TlAC8UbBABuEFkQB8askjm1sDKAAMAJAG8OAM11QAMhAfAAvgHo7j5wBKbGiIXpa8APzGKOhYuIRBIcBc-EKiEtKyAD6u7sD6vABcqSJiksAyUDnwSADcRESgkFABUsK08CxwGIQ1FNRmFkocaIbqtrwA2n2omDjAUBzRs3H4BH2GcIwzsfOmClaFfthOsq3tEJ3dnuGkpFHnHXBdGLykxZo6LAC6xcOc9U89Ua4GgVx6Rkel2e3UIAHJvAI2iw8BA8N5CkjhCiIABJOiIyR4VHozFEvD4uH6YFNaBQgCqLHExFIfX25kUrBGPFZMIhAwOUPBvXIBTG0XZFhs9hOzjcHh8RxlpzILx8xxViVCN0iVjs8q8vlswumfO%206tsDKZBC1yVVsMljCFfISwVChiiwqgH20un0OveEoFHL1yrleUVGuc4IDUCi0oNFpN4PNt290RpoKgjPEkLatBzBARWJxpJLqPxhK2JIxAnJlJStig5bxdGKcIAjAAmADMcNqzfrbagcIALABWABscKgnmpRCAA) that replicates the error.

---

I might have used an alternate version of the type `RouteUrl` in the following way:

- Loop through `RouteParams`
- Inside `Loop`, Replace each `Param` with `RouteParams`'s value.

I am talking about something like this code (but at type level):

```
    let url = '';

    const paramsKeys = Object.keys(routeParams) as (keyof typeof routeParams)[];

    paramsKeys.forEach((key) => {
      url = replace(url, `:${String(key)}`, routeParams[key]);
    });

    return url;
```

I already have a generic type for replacing parts of string:

```
export type Replace<
  Str extends string,
  Search extends string,
  Replacement extends string
> = Str extends `${infer Prefix}${Search}${infer Suffix}` ? `${Prefix}${Replacement}${Suffix}` : Str;
```

But I don't know, how we can **iterate** over keys of a `type` or an `interface`, that's why I can't write an alternate type for `RouteUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

```
type RouteUrl<
    Path extends string,
    Params extends RouteParams<Path>
> = Path extends `${infer Left}/:${infer Param}/${infer Right}`
    ? `${Left}/${Param extends keyof Params ? Params[Param] extends string ? Params[Param] : string : string}/${RouteUrl<Right, Params extends RouteParams<Right> ? Params : never>}`
    : Path extends `${infer Left}/:${infer Param}`
    ? `${Left}/${Param extends keyof Params ? Params[Param] extends string ? Params[Param] : string : string}`
    : Path;
```

this is how I think you can solve it.
I am not sure about the best solution. but until someone answers that, you can use mine.
as the code shows, I type guarded if the `Param` is a key of `Params` and the value of `Params[Params]` is a string, use the value. otherwise, use the type `string` (I used the type `string` but you might want to use a better default type for here)

Answer (score 0):

```
// split `a/b/c` into 'a'|'b'|'c'
type Split<T, D extends string> = T extends `${infer A}${D}${infer B}` ? A | Split<B, D> : T;

// every type that can be `${stringified}`
type Stringable = string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined

// pick `:${key}` params and make a record of them
type RouteParams<T extends string> = { [K in Split<T, '/'> as K extends `:${infer P}` ? P : never]: Stringable }

// map path `:param` to `map.param` or `never`
// leave `path` as is
type MapParameter<P extends string, M extends Record<string, Stringable>> =
  | P extends `:${infer K}` ? (
    K extends keyof M ? M[K] : never
  ) : P;

// with RouteParams check
// errors on missing parameter
type RouteUrl<
  Path extends string,
  Params extends RouteParams<Path>
> = _RouteUrlPiece<Path, Params>

// without RouteParams check, for recursion
// returns `never` on missing parameter 
type _RouteUrlPiece<
  Path extends string,
  Params extends Record<string, Stringable>
> =
  | Path extends `${infer A}/${infer B}` ? `${MapParameter<A, Params>}/${_RouteUrlPiece<B, Params>}`
  : MapParameter<Path, Params>
```